# What happens when you invoke a thread's interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to know what happens

1. when it is sleeping?
2. when it is running i.e., it is executing the given task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by your previous questions, I assume you are interested in Java's behavior.

In Java, an `InterruptedException` will be thrown if the thread is currently blocking. If the thread is not blocking, the exception will not be thrown.

For more information, look here:
[JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

For .NET languages, a `ThreadInterruptedException` will be thrown if the thread is currently blocking. If the thread isn't blocking the exception will not be thrown until the thread blocks.

Please tag your question with the language you want an answer for.

Comment: Similar story in Java, except that (1) the exception is called `InterruptedException`, and (2) the thread has an "interrupt status" that's set if the thread's not waiting or sleeping.  I'm not sure whether blocking with the interrupt status already set will cause the exception to be thrown, but it'd be the choice less likely to break stuff.

Answer (score 10):

Interrupting a thread is a state-safe way to cancel it, but the thread itself has to be coded to pay attention to interrupts. Long, blocking Java operations that throw `InterruptedException` will throw that exception if an `.interrupt()` occurs while that thread is executing.

The `.interrupt()` method sets the "interrupted" flag for that thread and interrupts any IO or sleep operations. It does nothing else, so it's up to your program to respond appropriately- and check its interrupt flag, via `Thread.interrupted()`, at regular intervals.

If a thread doesn't check for interruptions, it cannot safely be stopped. [`Thread.stop()` is unsafe to use.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) So you use `.interrupt()` to stop a thread, but when writing multithreaded code, it is up to you to make sure that `.interrupt()` will do something sensible. [This TechRepublic article is a pretty good tutorial.](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5144546.html)

Comment: **Hi Adam,** I think ***"Long, blocking Java operations that throw InterruptedException will throw that exception if an .interrupt() occurs while that thread is executing"*** is kind of other way around. You say a **thread is blocking** then it is because: 1) It has been put to sleep for a set amount of time 2) It is suspended with a call to suspend() and will be blocked until a resume() message 3) The thread is suspended by call to wait(), and will become runnable on a notify or notifyAll message. In all these above case the thread isn't executing anything it is in the blocked state. when int

Answer (score 1):

One more important information worth sharing is that, there are two methods in Thread Class
**isInterrupted()** and **interrupted()**. Latter one being a static method. **isInterrupted()** method call does not alter the state of interrupted attribute of Thread class, whereas **interrupted()**  static method call can will ***set the value of interrupted boolean value to false***.